# Capture a loop from analog vinyl to remix-deck?

Tags: traktor, turntables

I think about buying a NI-S8 or a Xone DB4 (yes, I know these are completely different things).. and a big decision-helper for me would be, if it is possible to capture a loop to the remix-deck.. BUT FROM ANALOG VINYL ?

I have read that it is possible to connect my Turntables to the S8 and play my vinyls through traktor.. but it is possible to loop the analog signal inside traktor?

Answer (score 2):

If your interface can accept the cable from your turntable (or you have an adaptor) then yes. External audio signals can be Live Input in Traktor.

I hope this is helpful. I have Komplete Kontrol and Maschine but have not used Traktor much.